Clarification of a lemma in fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups
I am using the book "Abstract Algebra theory and applications". In the proof of fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups in Chapter 13, there is a lemma as follows.
Lemma 13.9.
Let G
be a finite abelian p
-group and suppose that g∈G
has maximal order. Then G is isomorphic to ⟨g⟩×H
for some subgroup H
of G
.
The original proof is shown in http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/struct-section-finite-abelian-groups.html
I understood that gH must have maximal order in G/H, and by induction G/H≅⟨gH⟩×K/H for some subgroup K of G containing H.
What confused me is the following part that the author claims that ⟨g⟩ ∩ K = {e}:
If b ∈ ⟨g⟩ ∩ K, then bH ∈ ⟨gH⟩ ∩ K/H = {H}. But why ⟨gH⟩ ∩ K/H = {H}? It seems that there are no previous requirements on the relations between K/H and ⟨gH⟩.
Can anyone explain this for me? Thank you very much.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773

The notation $H\times K$ for subgroups of an abelian group is generally reserved for when $H\cap K=\lbrace e\rbrace$, otherwise you would write $HK$. So your missing step is implicit in the notation. Note that this is part of the induction assumption: it holds for $n=1$, as $H$ is trivial, and the assumption applied to $G/H$ is exactly what you need.

Thanks for your reply. Do you mean by that, in the lemma, H should also satisfy ⟨g⟩ ∩ H  = {e}, which is not explicitly written out in the original proof? If this is added to the lemma, then I can understand the proof by induction.

Yes, this is what I mean. However, I believe it is indeed explicitly written in the proof, namely when using the notation $\lbrace g\rbrace \times H$, as I noted in my answer.
